# How to implement solution to extract files from share point to blob or adls gen2

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have requirement to implement a solution for extracting files from share point to adls gen2 or blob storage.

I know we can do by using logic apps.
But looking for other some other possiblities.

Comment: Are there any specific things you are looking for in alternate solutions?

Comment: Not alternate.we dont have source type as sharepoint in adf.so, i am looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

The docs have a small mention about how you can [use the Copy Activity with HTTP Connector for SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online) that you could explore.

If this doesn't work out for you, Logic Apps are indeed a great to implement this. You could also trigger the Logic App from your Data Factory pipeline when needed.

You could use the [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) or [Webhook Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity) to trigger your Logic App.

Comment: Greatful for inputs .I am looking for solution   for extracting files from share point to blob by using logic apps.